# Am I incrementing my sliding window too far out?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sliding-window

I am working on solving [this question on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/) which finds the longest substring of a given string without repeating characters. My solution is working for some strings (such as 'pwwkew'), but not for others (such as 'ckilbkd'). Any suggestions?

```
public int LengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
    if (s.Length < 2) return s.Length;

    HashSet<char> existing = new HashSet<char>();
    Stack<string> vals = new Stack<string>();

    int start = 0;
    int end = 1;
    int result = 1;
    existing.Add(s[0]);

    while (end < s.Length && start < end)
    {
        if (!existing.Contains(s[end]))
        {
            if (end == (s.Length - 1))
            {
                result = s.Length - start;
                Console.WriteLine("here");
                break;
            }

            existing.Add(s[end]);
            end++;
        }
        else
        {
            var res = s.Substring(start, end - start);

            if (vals.Count == 0)
            {
                vals.Push(res);
                result = res.Length;
            }
            else if (res.Length > vals.Peek().Length)
            {
                vals.Pop();
                vals.Push(res);
                result = res.Length;
            }

            if (s[end] == s[end - 1])
            {
                start = end;
                end++;
            }
            else
                start++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @BrettCaswell yes just updated!

Comment: this is actually a fairly common code test.. if I recall, the optimum way to handle it is a tuple binary search tree

Comment: @BrettCaswell thanks, however I'm not sure how a Tuple Binary Search Tree would be relevant and/or useful in this case.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So exactly, what did you try?

Comment: yeah.. you're right @EricJ .. it was the first thing to come to mind, but one second thought.. I don't think it was right.. or applies

Comment: "Am I sliding my window too far out?" -- I think it's the other way round: You don't go far enough. For example if your string is `"abcabcdef"`, you only consider the string up to the first repetition and you don't get to the optimal part at the end.

Comment: And I think that instead of just keeping track of whether you've already seen a letter with a set, you should probably keep track of where you have seen that letter the last time, so that you can adjust the start of your window accordingly -- If you have a long string with a z ner the end, it doesn't really matter whether you have seen a z near the beginning.

Comment: @EricJ You should slide window as soon as duplicate letter is found. And same time, HashSet having letters indexes less than duplicate later's index in HashSet should be deleted. In your case you are just skipping duplicate letter.